# Index of congruence subgroups in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ modulo their centers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, profinite-groups, pro-p-groups

Let $\Gamma_i$ be the set of matrices in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ which are congruent to $1$ modulo $p^i$, that is they are the congruence subgroups. I know that $\Gamma_i$ is a pro-$p$ group and $\Gamma_i/\Gamma_{i+1}$ has cardinality $p^4$.

Is $\Gamma_{i}/Z(\Gamma_{i})$ again a pro-$p$ group?

Also, I would like to know the index of $\Gamma_{i+1}/Z(\Gamma_{i+1})$ inside $\Gamma_{i}/Z(\Gamma_{i})$ where $Z(\Gamma_{i+1})$ is the center of $\Gamma_{i+1}$.

Comment: If you take the quotient of $\Gamma_i/Z(\Gamma_i)$ by a normal open subgroup, isn't it isomorphic to a quotient of $\Gamma_i$ by a normal open subgroup ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why its true?

Comment: Let $G=\Gamma_i$, $H=\Gamma_i / Z(\Gamma_i)$ and $p:G \to H$ the projection. For every open normal subgroup $V$ of $H$, you can show that $U=p^{-1}(V)$ is an open normal subgroup of $G$ containing $Z(\Gamma_i)$. So one one hand, $G/U$ is a $p$-group, and on the other hand, $G/U \simeq H/V$.

Comment: In my case, when $V=\Gamma_{i+1}/Z(\Gamma_{i+1})$, is $U=Z(\Gamma_i)\Gamma_{i+1}$?

Comment: I just tried to answer your first question, about $\Gamma_i/Z(\Gamma_i)$ being a pro-$p$-group

Comment: $\Gamma_i$ is a pro-$p$-group (for $i\ge 1$, not for $i=0$). A quotient of a pro-$p$-group by a closed normal subgroup is still a pro-$p$-group. (The center of $\Gamma_i$ is not open.)

Comment: Now asked also on MathOverflow: [Index of the congruence subgroups of $PGL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/321490). It is recommended to link both copies to each other if you ask on both sites. (See: [Guidelines for “Legitimate” CrossPosting?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5085#5088) and [Asking the same question on MSE and MO](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16288).)